# Angular2 Http double subscribe

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-http

Is it possible to call `Subscribe` method two times?

I'm trying to build api factory, which saves data in the factory, but that data can be use by different component on each ajax call.

factory

```
export class api {

    result = [];

    constructor (protected http: Http) { }

    getData ()
    {
        return this.http.get('./friends.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => this.result = res);
    }
}
```

test component, which is calling `subscribe` method again

```
export class TestPage {

    showListResult; 

    constructor (protected api: api) {

        this.api.getData().subscribe(res => this.showListResult = res)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return new Observable wrapper. Something like this should work:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'

export class api {

    result = [];

    constructor (protected http: Http) { }

    getData () {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            this.http.get('./friends.json')
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => {
                    this.result = res;
                    observer.next(res);
                    observer.complete();
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove share part, and check my answer. The point in using `new Observable` and `observer.next(res);`.

Comment: The example I posted is how it should be. Make sure you import Observable.

Comment: what does 'observer.next(res);' and `observer.complete();` do?

Comment: @dfsq what is this the advantage of doing this rather than just sharing the original observable?

Comment: @MarkM I posted this version after you already had given share answer (why delete it? it is useful).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the HTTP request once, and share the result to multiple subscribers, then I suggest using a connectable observer that publishes and replays the last value emitted:

```
this.observable = http.get('...').map(t=> t.json()).publishReplay().refCount();
```

Each new subscriber will replay the last emitted value without making a new HTTP request.

[Demo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHozknJ1sL6Ns1lLU4fG?p=preview)

This answer is similar to this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600088/pattern-for-sharereplay1-in-rxjs5).

Comment: Thanks for that comment - I deleted the answer because it's clearly wrong. Now off to dig through some code I thought was working properly…

Answer (score 0):

For later versions you can use the
`.share()` from RxJs, (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share).

`.publishReplay().refCount()` as described by pixelbits is deprecated and replaced by `.share()` to be able to not call the method again but actually subscribe to the return data.