# rxjs using promise only once on subscribe

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I wanted to use `rxjs` for the first time but am a bit stucked 'cause it doesn't behave exactly like I want it to: In my scenario I want to create an observable from a promise. But I want the promise only being called once (not on every subscription) and I want it not being called on creation time (defer the call to the first subscription).

First I tried this:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(_this.getMyPromise())
```

which causes a call to the `getMyPromise` function right on creation time. This is not satisfying because at that time I don't know if the source really will be used.

Then I tried:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.defer(function() { return _this.getMyPromise() })
```

which causes a call to the `getMyPromise` function each time a new subscription is being made to source. This makes way too many unnecessary calls to the web server. The `Rx.Observable.create` function seems to have the same issue.

So what is left or what am I missing?

Comment: So you only want it to be called once, but what do you want it to do if it is called after it is already completed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.shareReplay()` does this, e.g.:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.defer(function() { return _this.getMyPromise() }).shareReplay();
```

If you're using rxjs5, you'll want to read: [Pattern for shareReplay(1) in RxJS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600088/pattern-for-sharereplay1-in-rxjs5)

In answer to your comment below, I can think of a fairly straightforward extension to the above logic that will do what you want, but it has a caveat. Let's say the events you want to use to trigger a "refresh" are represented in a stream, s$, then you could do something like:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.of({}).concat(s$)
    .flatMapLatest(function() {
        return Rx.Observable.defer(function() {
            return _this.getMyPromise()
        })
    })
    .shareReplay(1)
```

What we have here is a stream starting with a dummy object to get things rolling, followed by a stream consisting of your refresh events. Each of these is projected into a new observable created from a fresh invocation of your getMyPromise method, and the whole thing is flattened into a single stream. Finally, we keep the shareReplay logic so we only actually make calls when we should.

The caveat is that this will only work properly if there's always at least one subscriber to the source (the first subscription after all others are disposed will run the promise again, and will receive both the previously-cached value and the result of the promise it caused to run).

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Is there a way to combine your solution with a reload mechanism on a callback? --> An event gets fired on which I could perform a call on a rxjs-callback-method. When this method gets called it performs a new call on _this.getMyPromise() and every subscriber gets informed about the new data? I know this is far more than I initialy asked, but it's just the next thing that comes to my mind...

Comment: TBH, I'm kinda baffled that fromPromise doesn't accept a callback like everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that does not require at least one subscriber at the source at all times using a simple helper:

```
var _p = null;
var once = function() { return _p || (_p = _this.getMyPromise());

var source = Rx.Observable.defer(once);
```

Or if you're using lodash, you can `_.memoize` your `getMyPromise` and get this automatically.

Comment: The caveat in my answer only applies to the second requirement. How could this approach be adapted to address this? Setting _p back to null will cause new subscribers to obtain a new promise, but how would you arrange to push the result of a new promise to existing subscribers?