# RxJs Create Observable from resulting Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs

Im fairly new to RxJs and I would like to understand what the best way is to work with Rx in combination with Promises.

What I want to create is a service in Angular that acts much as an event dispatcher pattern and emits an event once a promise is complete. What I also require is that, if there are no (event) subscribers the observable never gets called. The last thing I want to happen is that any subsequent subscribers to the observable get the same result without triggering another request to the server.
I have managed to implement my own solution here:

```js
// ... CountryService code

var COUNTRIES_LOADED = Rx.Observable
    .create(function (observer) {
        $http
            .get('/countries')
            .then(function (res) {
                observer.onNext(res);
            }, function (err) {
                observer.onError(err);
            })
            .finally(function () {
                observer.onCompleted();
            });
    })
    .shareReplay();
```

Now anytime I subscribe a new "listener" to subject the observable will be pulled. Any new subscribers will get the value cached without touching the server again.

So inside my "consumer" (Angular Directive) I would like to do something like this:

```js
// ... countryInput directive code:

COUNTRIES_LOADED.subscribe(function (response) {
    // Fill in countries into scope or ctrl
    scope.countries = response.countries;
});
```

Any future subscribers to the COUNTRIES_LOADED observer MUST NOT trigger an $http request. Likewise, if the directive is never included on the page, $http will never get called.

The solution above works, however I am not aware of the potential drawbacks and memory implications of this approach. Is this a valid solution? Is there a better / more appropriate way to achieve this using RxJs?

Many thanks!

Comment: check this link using rxjs with angularjs http://cvuorinen.net/2016/05/using-rxjs-observables-with-angularjs-1/

Comment: Your solution looks fine, I don't think that you can come up with something better than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here (Just slightly differently named)
[rxjs using promise only once on subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935386/rxjs-using-promise-only-once-on-subscribe)

So for my example the answer is as simple as:

```
var loadCountries = function () { return $http.get('/countries'); };

var observable = Rx.Observable.defer(loadCountries).shareReplay();
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise)`

**fromPromise:**

> Converts a Promises/A+ spec compliant Promise and/or ES2015 compliant
>   Promise or a factory function which returns said Promise to an
>   Observable sequence.

**example:**

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

---

**update**

rxjs6 method is [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from)

Answer (score 6):

**update**

As of **rxjs6** you can use [`from()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from)

---

Did you tried to use the `fromPromise()` API of **rxjs5** ?

Check it's documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise) !

Comment: Yes I am aware of the fromPromise, but that one happens only when there already is a promise present. What I require is that a $http call is never executed if there are no subscribers to the observable

Comment: any idea how to use it in ***rxjs v.6***?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use Observables
Lets say you have a method called `getuser(username)`.

```
//Returns an observable
getUser(username){
    return $http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And you can use it as below

```
getUser.subscribe(res => console.log(response));
```

BUT if you want to use promises

```
//Returns an Promise
//Donot forget to import toPromise operator
getUser(username){
    return $http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .toPromise();
}
```

And you can use it as below

```
getUser.then(res => console.log(response));
```

Comment: Ok sorry maybe the question was not very clear. I do know how to use and consume observables, What I want to know is how to "wrap" an HTTP call inside an observable that only gets called if AND ONLY if there is/are any subscribers.

Comment: The major problem with this answer is that `$http.get` *does not* return an Observable. It returns a Promise. That's the big difference between Angular's `Http` and AngularJS's `$http`.