# angular 5 post request returns twice

Tags: angular, post, request

After I login, authservice is called and then the routing works to the profilecomponent.

However the post request is being sent twice, I am not using Cors so I am assuming this can't be a preflighted request?
Profile.component.ts ngoninit seems to run twice, as I first receive coinId with the correct id followed by an undefined coinId.

```
  5a273e34f5c5643e18c035dacoinId from profile2!
  main.f2eaf663cdbf963d2af8.bundle.js:1 undefinedcoinId from profile2!
```

I am quite new to all this, I am contemplating starting a nginx server but not sure if that would solve this issue.

**login.component.ts**

```
   let url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/login';
   this.newService.login( url, user, user.username).subscribe(result => {

var value = result["user"];
var coinId = result.user.coinid;
this.router.navigate(['/profile', coinId]);
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
  login(url: string, user: any, username: any)
  {return this.http.post(url , user)
  .do (res => this.setSession(res))
  }

  private setSession(authResult) {

        const expiresAt = moment().add(authResult.expiresIn,'second');
        this.loggedIn.next(!!localStorage.getItem('id_token'));

      console.log(authResult.token + "dit is de token");
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

        localStorage.setItem("expires_at", JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()) );

    }
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
  var coinId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
 console.log(coinId + "coinId from profile2!")


    this.router.navigate( [ '/profile', {outlets: { formOutlet: 
    ['profileform', coinAId]}}] );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to Angular but you can use **`shareReplay()`** to avoid multicasting your POST request. RxSwift provides different operators when you have multiple subscriptions to the same Observable and want to ensure that your code is not being re-executed for subscriptions again & again or until the subscription is expired.  The available operators are  replay(), replayAll(), , publish(), share(), and shareReplay().

Try to change your code like below:

```
login(url: string, user: any, username: any)
  {return this.http.post(url , user)
  .do (res => this.setSession(res))
  .shareReplay()
  }
```

`shareReplay()` ensures a single subscription. `shareReplay` will replay events from the source observable to subscribers once those events are sent. As per documentation :

> Returns an observable sequence that shares a single subscription to the underlying sequence replaying notifications subject to a maximum time length for the replay buffer. This operator is a specialization of replay that connects to the
>   connectable observable sequence when the number of observers goes from
>   zero to one, and disconnects when there are no more observers.

[Github Docs & Example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md)

[Also See this question on Stackoverflow with simplified explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600088/pattern-for-sharereplay1-in-rxjs5)